# Outputting a list of the intersecting genes/Values when making a VennDiagram in R with the VennDiagram package

Tags: r, output

I made a VennDiagram with five intersecting vectors, each containing a set of gene names.

Does anyone know whether I can somehow export the list of genes, which overlap in the different intersections?

I know I can do that with several online tools, such as Venny or InteractiVenn, but it would be much more convenient in R.

This is the code I use:

```
venn.diagram(
  x = list(set1, set2, set3, set4, set5),
  category.names = c("set1", "set2", "set3", "set4", "set5"),
  filename= "my_path/venn.png",
  output=NULL,
   # # Output features
        imagetype="png" ,
        height = 2000 ,
        width = 2000 ,
        units = "px",
        na = 'stop',
        resolution = 300,
        compression = "lzw",
        lwd = 2,
        col = c("#1ABC9C", "#85C1E9", "#CD6155", "#5B2C6F", "#F8C471"), 
        cat.col = c("#1ABC9C", "#85C1E9", "#CD6155", "#5B2C6F", "#F8C471"), 
        fill = c(alpha("#1ABC9C",0.3), alpha("#85C1E9",0.3), alpha("#CD6155",0.3), alpha("#5B2C6F",0.3), alpha("#F8C471",0.3)), 
          cex = 1.5,
          fontfamily = "sans",
          cat.cex = 1.15,
          cat.default.pos = "text",
          cat.fontfamily = "sans",
          cat.dist= c(0.055),
          cat.pos= c(1)
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the OP has moved on, but I had the same question.
Here's what I came up with for a five set example- NB this uses a different package:

```
    require(nVennR)
    require(dplyr)
       # wrangle input
    Venn <- plotVenn(list("set1"=set1, "set2"=set2, "set3"=set3, "set4"=set4, 
    "set5"=set5), outFile = "DataSourceVenn.svg") # produces associated diagram
      # generate lists of each intersect
    intersects <- listVennRegions(Venn)
      # pull lists together
    intersects <- plyr::ldply(intersects, cbind)
      # insert own appropriate col name for V1
    colnames(intersects)<-c('Intersect','V1')
      # transpose data into columns for each intersect
    intersects <- dcast(setDT(intersects), rowid(Intersect) ~ Intersect, value.var = 
    "V1")[,Intersect:=NULL]
```